# How can I force a DataGridView to redraw?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I have a DataGridView which uses a BindingSource. This BindingSource points to a read-only property, which is a collection of `department` objects. When I programmatically add a department to the property, I am having trouble getting the DataGridView to redraw itself + show the new department.

If I set a breakpoint, I verify that the property has the new department; yet the DataGridView does not draw it. If I navigate away from the tab, and then back, the DataGridView displays the new department.

My question is essentially, **how can I programmatically trigger whatever happens when I navigate away from and then back to the DataGridview**, to force it to redraw (or force its BindingSource to update)? I've tried all the following:

```
AffectedDepartmentsBindingSource.CancelEdit()
AffectedDepartmentsBindingSource.EndEdit()
AffectedDepartmentsBindingSource.ResetBindings(False)
AffectedDepartmentsBindingSource.ResetBindings(True)

AffectedDepartmentsDataGridView.Refresh()
AffectedDepartmentsDataGridView.Update()
AffectedDepartmentsDataGridView.Hide()
AffectedDepartmentsDataGridView.Show()
```

---

Here's the property:

```
Public ReadOnly Property affectedDepartments As SortableBindingList(Of Department)
    Get
        Dim uniqueDeptIds As New ArrayList
        Dim _affectedDepartments As New SortableBindingList(Of Department)

        'Go through products
        For Each p As product In products.Where(Function(pr) pr.isNotACopy)
            If Not uniqueDeptIds.Contains(p.cs_dept_id) Then
                uniqueDeptIds.Add(p.cs_dept_id)
                Dim d As New Department With {
                    .schedule = Me,
                    .name = p.department,
                    .cs_dept_id = p.cs_dept_id
                }
                _affectedDepartments.Add(d)
            End If
        Next

        'Add temp departments
        If _tempDepartment IsNot Nothing Then
            _affectedDepartments.Add(_tempDepartment)
        End If

        Return _affectedDepartments
    End Get
End Property
```

Comment: is this WPF or winforms

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like this:

```
Me.DataGridView1.Invalidate()
```

**Edit**

The reason why you don't see the added items is because you create a new instance each time.

You should do it like this:

```
Public ReadOnly Property affectedDepartments As SortableBindingList(Of Department)
    Get

        Dim uniqueDeptIds As New ArrayList

        If (_affectedDepartments Is Nothing) Then
            _affectedDepartments = New SortableBindingList(Of Department)
        End If

        'Go through products
        For Each p As product In products.Where(Function(pr) pr.isNotACopy)
            If Not uniqueDeptIds.Contains(p.cs_dept_id) Then
                uniqueDeptIds.Add(p.cs_dept_id)
                Dim d As New Department With {
                    .schedule = Me,
                    .name = p.department,
                    .cs_dept_id = p.cs_dept_id
                }
                _affectedDepartments.Add(d)
            End If
        Next

        'Add temp departments
        If _tempDepartment IsNot Nothing Then
            _affectedDepartments.Add(_tempDepartment)
        End If

        Return _affectedDepartments

    End Get
End Property

Private _affectedDepartments As SortableBindingList(Of Department)
```

Comment: The reason I did this is because I wanted it to get a fresh list each time it was requested, instead of using a 'cached', probably stale version of the list. Is there a way to use the private variable, but force it to 'recalculate' each time its requested?

Comment: I think this is how you should do it. If not, you'll need to rebind the grid each time, which will result of lost scrolling and selections. I suggest you create a _push_ mechanism which looks for updates at a given interval.

Comment: I implemented this, but it's still not refreshing the grid.

Comment: Maybe if I tell you what I'm trying to accomplish it will help. I set the `_tempDepartment` variable in a dialogue box, and then I want the `affectedDepartments` collection to update and the DataGridView to refresh.

Comment: Then you'll have to move everything inside of the property into a method like `Private Sub UpdateAffectedDepartments()`. When the dialog closes with `If (mydialog.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) Then` you update the data source by calling `Me.UpdateAffectedDepartments()`.

Comment: Also, make sure the `SortableBindingList` implements `IBindingList` interface.

Answer (score 1):

you can refresh the DataGridView

```
Datagrid.Items.Refresh()
```